# How do I generate and email a PDF generated with DOMPDF at the same time?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dompdf

I have a problem using the `DOMPDF` library to generate a pdf and at the same time send it by mail.

What I need is that the moment you click on a button in html is generated and sent the pdf file at the same time; So far only send me the mail with a pdf already generated, but I need the pdf to be generated and sent.
The data is collected first in a database and then the pdf is generated with the most recent record in the database.

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you

Note: without using frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use either the built-in SMTP functions of PHP or use a library such as PHPMailer (not a framework)

Once your PDF is generated, save it somewhere on the server, hold on to the full path to the PDF file and call a mail script to send the mail with an attachment (the attachment being the PDF)

Using PHP Mailer it could look something like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->addAddress('your_email@example.com');
$mail->addAttachment('/path/to/your/file.pdf', 'name as shown in the email.pdf');
$mail->send();
```

Of course you'd have to configure your mail with the host from where it will be sent, authenticate etc... but that wasn't what you asked for.

Just replace `/path/to/your/file.pdf` with whatever the path is + filename of your PDF file (on the server) and replace `name as shown in the email.pdf` with the name you want the receiver of the email to see, for example 'invoice.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBNAME','user');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('PASS','');
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,DBUSER,PASS);
$q_sel="SELECT name,email from user_details";
$stmt_query=$dbh->prepare($q_sel);
$user_detail_exe=$stmt_query->execute();
$user_details=$stmt_query->fetchAll();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Send Email Generating Dompdf
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="send_email.php">
            <input type="submit" value="EMAIL"  />
            <table  style="width:100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                foreach ($user_details as $user_detail)
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $user_detail['name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $user_detail['email'];?></td>            
                    </tr>
                <?php   
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

send_email.php

```
<?php 
$name='user_detaiil.pdf';
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
require_once 'Swift/lib/swift_required.php'; 
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBNAME','user');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('PASS','');
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,DBUSER,PASS);
$q_sel="SELECT name,email from user_details";
$stmt_query=$dbh->prepare($q_sel);
$user_detail_exe=$stmt_query->execute();
$user_details=$stmt_query->fetchAll();
$pdf_data='<html>
            <body>
                <table style="width:100%" border="1">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>';
                    foreach ($user_details as $user_detail)
                    {

                        $pdf_data.='<tr>
                            <td>'.$user_detail['name'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$user_detail['email'].'</td>          
                        </tr>';
                    }

                $pdf_data.='</table>
            </body>
        </html>';


    $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_data);
    $dompdf->render();
    $canvas =$dompdf->get_canvas();
    $date = date("d/m/Y");
    $canvas->page_text(10, 770,"Date: $date" , $font, 12);
    $canvas->page_text(520, 770, "Page: {PAGE_NUM}", $font, 12);
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $file_to_save = 'reports/user_detail.pdf';
    file_put_contents($file_to_save, $output);
    //$dompdf->stream($name);
    ob_start();
    $HasFunctions = true;
    $SendsMail = true;

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

    ->setSubject('User Detail Report')

    ->setFrom(array('test@gmail.com'))

    ->setTo(array('test@gmail.com'))

    ->setBody($messagetext, 'text/html');

    $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath("reports/user_detail.pdf"));

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("smtp.fake.com", 25)
    ->setUsername("Username")
    ->setPassword("Password");

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    unlink("reports/user_detail.pdf");
    if($result)
    {
        header("LOCATION:dompdf.php");
    }
?>
```